# How is the calculation of types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

Lets say

```
  flip :: (a->b->c) ->b->a->c
  const ::d->e->d
```

type of (flip const) would be

```
  a=d,b=e,c=d
```

in

```
  b->a->c
```

so the type would be

```
  e->d->d
```

But for (map take) its

```
  [Int]->[[a]]->[[a]]
```

so i didn't understand how the ghci this one calculated.
i understood the [[a]]->[[a]] but why and how [Int] ?

edit: For example if we'd write in ghci

```
  :t flip const 


it would return b->c->c
```

and ghci would calculate that as i did.

But

```
 map :: (a->b)->[a]->[b]
 take :: Int->[c]->[c]
```

so why is map take

```
  [Int]->[[a]->[a]]
```

why [Int] how did the ghci calculate that

Comment: It is `[Int] -> [[a] -> [a]]`, not `[Int]->[[a]]->[[a]]`. Note the difference in square brackets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should copy and paste the types you see, not re-type them into the question.  The reason is you saw wrong.  The type for `map take` is:

```
map take :: [Int] -> [[a] -> [a]]
```

In other words, the unification works as such:

```
:t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
:t take
take :: Int -> [c] -> [c]
```

so when applying `take` as the first argument to `map` you get `a ~ Int` and `b ~ [c] -> [c]` (notice that is a function).  Performing these replacements in the `map` type and applying the first argument:

```
map take :: [a] -> [b]        (for some specific 'a' and 'b')
-- recall a ~ Int
map take :: [Int] -> [b]      (for some specific 'b')
-- recall b ~ [c] -> [c]
map take :: [Int] -> [[c] -> [c]]
```

Yay, `map take` is exactly what you expect.  A function that operates over lists of Ints and results in a list of functions that will take some number of elements from the start of a list.

Comment: Does this have a topic name in haskell?  I searched 'haskell type unification' but I didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: This is highly relevant https://docs.google.com/file/d/1oTZkzY1MiQwUAdoW3E5Fsb7p6AYRU4ph9BrR17TC-Qrzh-6vHUS6mRatgZhL/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It appears to be on the money.

Comment: Unification is not a Haskell-specific concept, it's a more general term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)

Answer (score 15):

Let's do the same analysis:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

And

```
take :: Int -> [x] -> [x]
```

But that actually means

```
take :: Int -> ([x] -> [x])
```

So with `a=Int` and `b=([x] -> [x])`  you get

```
map take :: [Int] -> [ [x] -> [x] ]
```

A list of list functions!